# Are free groups simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be the free group of finite rank $n>1$. Is $F_n$ simple? I know that every subgroup of $F_n$ is free, but I don't know how to tell whether it's a normal subgroup.

Comment: Can you think of any nontrivial homomorphisms $F_n \to G$ for some group $G$? Then the kernel of the homomorphism will be a normal subgroup. How about $G = \mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: @Quasicoherent Oh, I see. So I can map $F_n \to \Bbb Z^n$ where the $i$th component of the output counts the number of occurrences of the $i$th generator. E.g. $F_2 \to \Bbb Z^2$ maps $aba^{-1} b^{-1}$ to $(0,0)$. So then the kernel is definitely a normal subgroup...in particular it's the commutator subgroup, right?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is the abelianization of $F_n$ (it's the free *abelian* group of rank $n$), so the kernel is the commutator subgroup.

Comment: It's clearly false for $n=1$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yeah I saw before how it is false for $n=1$ because then $F_1 \cong \Bbb Z$. Should have remarked that in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Free groups have *lots* of normal subgroups. This can be seen by combining the normal subgroup/homomorphism duality given by the first isomorphism theorem to the universal property of free groups, which says that every group is the quotient of *some* free group. In particular, if $G$ is an $n$-generated group then there a normal subgroup $N$ of the free group on $n$-generators $F_n$ such that $F_n/N\cong G$.

For example, the subgroup $N=\langle a^2, b^2, ba^2b^{-1}, ab^2a^{-1}, (ab)^2\rangle$ of the free group $F(a, b)$ is normal, and the quotient group $F(a, b)/N$ is the Klein $4$-group. (Proving that $N$ is normal is not difficult, and in fact this is the subgroup $F_2(X^2)$ mentioned at the end of this post.)

Lets just consider the free groups of finite rank $n\geq 2$, denoted $F_n$. Now, as I said above, we know that these groups have *lots* of normal subgroups...so what do they look like? Well, we know that they are free, but the following result says that their generators are hard to write down:

> **Theorem.**
>   A non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $F_n$ has finite index if and only if it is finitely generated.

Hence, if $F_n/N$ is infinite then $N$ has infinite rank; it is hard to write down!

There are other results which say that the subgroups are hard to write down. For example, there are finitely generated groups $F_n/N$ which are not recursively presentable (as there are uncountably many $2$-generated groups but only countably many recursively presentable $2$-generated groups); this means that we cannot algorithmically (use a computer to) describe the corresponding normal subgroup $N$.

Also, weirdly, there are normal subgroups $N$ of $F_n$ such that we cannot determine if an arbitrary element $W$ of $F_n$ is contained in $N$. This statement is just a re-phrasing of the insolubility of the word problem for groups.

---

Now, for some positive results. A *verbal subgroup* is a subgroup generated by all words of a specific form. More precisely: Let $W_{\mu}(X_{\lambda})$, where $\mu=1, 2, \ldots$, be a set of words in the symbols $X_{\lambda}$, where $\lambda=1, 2,\ldots$. Then the *$\{W_{\mu}\}$-verbal subgroup $G(W_{\mu})$ of a group $G$* is the subgroup of $G$ generated by all the elements of the form $W_{\mu}(g_{\lambda})$ where $g_{\lambda}$ ranges over $G$.

Verbal subgroups are always normal (why?). The first examples are:

- $G(X_1X_2X_1^{-1}X_2^{-1})$ is the derived subgroup
- $G(X)$ is the whole group $G$
- $G(X_1X_2)$ is also the whole group $G$ (take $X_1=g$ and $X_2=1$ for all $g\in G$)
- $F_n(X^2)$ has finite index, and so has finite rank. This is because every non-trivial element of $F_n/F_n(X^2)$ has order two, and so (by a standard exercise) this group is abelian. It is then also finite (this uses that $F_n$ is finitely generated).

Comment: Can I claim "the rank of a normal subgroup of a free group has no clear relationship with the rank of the free group"?

It seems, the rank of a normal subgroup is the smallest cardinality of relations, which depends on what words we choose to include. So it doesn't matter what the cardinality of the original generating set is?

As in, even if we start from a finite set $S$, we can still have infinitely many words as relations, each independent of each other, and they will generate a normal subgroup with an infinite rank.

Comment: The rank of the free group $F$ still influences the rank of the normal subgroups. In particular, a free group cannot contain normal subgroups of *smaller* rank. For example, the free group of rank $4$ contains no normal subgroups of ranks $1$, $2$ or $3$. If your free group $F$ is finitely generated of rank at least $2$, then all non-finitely generated normal subgroups are isomorphic - they are finitely generated of countable rank [this uses the axiom of choice though...].